# why shard need much storage?

Tags: linux, mongodb, sharding

i am testing shard function of mongodb,i insert 30278845 document to a collection ,the disk status now is

```
# ls
configDb  shard1-1  shard2-1
# du -csh shard1-1/
87G     shard1-1/
# du -csh shard2-1/
90G     shard2-1/
```

this is collection document , i do not understand why so much space will be occupied?

```
mongos> db.testtable.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b6780"), "name" : "6BScn0", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000000"), "name" : "HXnAZv", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b6910"), "name" : "kRZXj3", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000001"), "name" : "3K4lev", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b6974"), "name" : "A0D2wo", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000002"), "name" : "AmhkRV", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b6a3c"), "name" : "17mVkj", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000003"), "name" : "E8t6Jf", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b6b68"), "name" : "0u8vhV", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000004"), "name" : "ZNCzlL", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b6cf8"), "name" : "DmCJRp", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000005"), "name" : "s3JPDJ", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b6fb4"), "name" : "C9GE0B", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000006"), "name" : "kHtp3I", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b7018"), "name" : "nrcUYc", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000007"), "name" : "VD4cYW", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b720c"), "name" : "bK6HdH", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000008"), "name" : "7C5AJO", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1ce8a4c8b466d008b75f4"), "name" : "5ZdZDj", "age" : 13 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a1b9920c30fb7000000009"), "name" : "QIBshX", "age" : 13 }
Type "it" for more
```

Comment: Is each shard a replica set ? 
Can you run db.testtable.stats() to check how much space testtable collection took ?

Answer (score 0):

i reread the doc about mongodb storage ,and figure it out,doc says

the default alloation is approximately 5% of disk space on 64-bit installations.

and my disk status is

```
/dev/sda7             1.8T  176G  1.5T  11% /
```

and i have two shard on the disk ,total is 90*2G ,that's the reasion :)